# tex4ebook generates incorrect hyperlink references

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, htlatex, tex4ebook

I am sorry that I am unable to extract a minimal working example.

I downloaded the source code from [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/e-print/1110.5001), commented out `\usepackage{times,fullpage}` and `\usepackage{xr-hyper}` in the preamble:

```latex
\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\usepackage{times,fullpage}

% For cross-file-references
%\usepackage{xr-hyper}

% Package for hypertext links:
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

and compiled with the configure file

```latex
\Preamble{xhtml,pic-align}

\Configure{Picture}{.svg}  
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\def\patchaccent#1{%
  \csletcs{orig#1}{#1}
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname##1{\Picture+{}\csname orig#1\endcsname{##1}\EndPicture}
}
\patchaccent{acute}
\patchaccent{bar}
\patchaccent{breve}
\patchaccent{check}
\patchaccent{ddot}
\patchaccent{dot}
\patchaccent{grave}
\patchaccent{tilde}
\patchaccent{vec}
\patchaccent{widehat}
\patchaccent{widetilde}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

and the mk4 file

```lua
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  -- Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
  Make:htlatex {}
  -- Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end

Make:tex4ht{}
Make:t4ht{}
```

I found that the generated epub file has many incorrect hyperlinks of references. For example, the generated code of label of Lemma 2.4:

```html
<a id="x3-3002r3"></a>
<span class="cmbx-10">Lemma 2.4.</span>
```

while in the reference code of Lemma 2.4 in Remark 2.5 is

```html
The following fact was used in the proof of Lemma <a href="#x3-3002r4">2.4<!--tex4ht:ref: lemma-cech --></a>:
```

The reference ID is incorrect (and in fact, there is no `#x3-3002r4` according to the generated `.aux` file). It's weird that some of the references are correct, while others are wrong.

I look forward to a fix of this.

======

## Update

I produced a minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}[subsection]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\subsection{A}

\begin{thm}
  \label{thm:nul}
  nul
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  \label{thm:this}
  This is a theorem
\end{thm}

Look at Theorem \ref{thm:nul}.

Look at Theorem \ref{thm:this}.

\end{document}
```

compiled with tex4ebook without any extra arguments.

Note that the environment `thm` uses the counter of `subsection`. See the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems) for such a usage.

Comment: I can see that  this happens, but it seems to be completely random. When I  copy parts of this document to a new one, with the same preamble, links works.

Comment: @michal.h21 It seems that there is some confliction between counting/labeling system. I found that all lemmas are referred by `Lemma <a href="#x3-****r?">*.?` where two question marks indicates the same number, while the label of lemma looks like `#x3-****r`, where the number after `r` is not necessarily the number of the lemma.

Comment: @michal.h21 I understood what's happening. I produced an MWE and will update the answer soon. It is very probable a typo of the template that author uses, but since pdflatex will give us the right hyperlink, it is still reasonable to see whether we can do something.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I found that it doesn't have any anwswer now. I think the issue was fixed in the meantime, as I get a correct result with up-to-date TeX4ht.

This is the rendered HTML:

[image]

And this is the HTML code:

```html
<div class='newtheorem'>
<!-- l. 14 --><p class='noindent'><span class='head'>
<a id='x1-2001r2'></a>
<span class='cmbx-10'>Theorem 1.2.</span>  </span> <span class='cmti-10'>nul</span>
</p>
  </div>
<!-- l. 17 --><p class='indent'>
</p>
  <div class='newtheorem'>
<!-- l. 19 --><p class='noindent'><span class='head'>
<a id='x1-2002r2'></a>
<span class='cmbx-10'>Theorem 1.3.</span>  </span> <span class='cmti-10'>This is a theorem</span>
</p>
  </div>
<!-- l. 22 --><p class='indent'>
  Look at Theorem <a href='#x1-2001r2'>1.2<!-- tex4ht:ref: thm:nul  --></a> .
</p><!-- l. 26 --><p class='indent'>  Look at Theorem <a href='#x1-2002r3'>1.3<!-- tex4ht:ref: thm:this  --></a> .
</p>
```